# What is the meaning of "lurid press" in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "lurid press" in the following context?

> In recent years **lurid press** reports have blamed mass poaching on rebel movements and armed militias, especially Somalia's Al Shabaab, tying two together two evils - poaching and terrorism. [Source](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/ivory-9781849046763?prevSortField=1&prevNumResPerPage=20&lang=en&cc=us#)

I couldn't find its meaning as a separate expression, if it is a common one at all. Does it mean "sensational press"?

Comment: You are misreading it as lurid press, whereas it means lurid (press reports) --  the news articles are lurid in trying to vilify the terrorists further, by reporting that they also steal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the **press reports** that are being described as lurid, not the press. But I think you're right about the meaning - sensational.

(More often, "lurid" means grisly, violent, disturbing, but in this sentence the author is talking about the blaming, not the details of the poaching.)